# recursive call overflows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, recursion

On a test data set the following code works, but when I change to a second test set with a similar size it overflows.

To change a string of tokens into an associated new string of tokens I use this vector lookup function

```
//looks for input string in vector and returns output, 'c' is check row, 'r' is return row
string vectorSearch(string &check, int &direction, int n, int c, int r, int level) 
{
    if ((direction == 1 && check.length() <= 1) || n == list.size()-1 ||(direction == 0 && check.length() > 1)) { //if reading and string is 1 char then pass over
        if (direction == 1){ //convert '???' into '?'
            string temp = "";
            bool wildToken = false;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < check.length(); i++) {
                temp+='?';
                if (check.compare(temp) == 0) { check = '?'; wildToken = false; } //done,'???" case, return '?' token
                else if (check[i] == '?') wildToken = true; //not done searching
            }
        }

        return check;
    } else {
        if (list[n][c] == check || list[n][c] == ('0'+check)) //add dummy '0'
            return list[n][r];
        else 
            return vectorSearch (check, direction, n+1, c, r, level);
    }
}
```

After working fine for a dozen conversions the stack overflows

vectorSearch is called from this function

```
//this function takes an ontology and direction==1 (default) changes from string 
//to single char or if direction==0 takes single char and converts to string representation
string Lexicon::convertOntology(string input, int level, int direction, string out, string temp) 
{
    if (input == "" && temp == "") 
        return out; //check for completed conversion
    else {
        if (direction == 0 || input[0] == '.' || input[0] == '-' || input == "" ) { //found deliniator or end
            if (temp == "") temp = input[0]; //condition for reverse w/o deleniators
            if (input != "") return convertOntology(input.substr(1), level+1, direction, 
                out+=vectorSearch(temp, direction, 0, direction, 1-direction, level));
            else {
                string empty = "";
                return convertOntology(empty, level+1, direction, out+=vectorSearch(temp, direction, 0, direction, 1-direction, level));
            }
        } else 
            return convertOntology(input.substr(1), level, direction, out, temp+=input[0]); //increment and check
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is too complex. Recursive functions shouldn't be used in such complex code.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Rollie, Question: why does my code not work when it should- A) need more RAM, B) need to allocate more RAM with some compiler setting, C) code is brain dead an should be rewritten, D) some bug causing issue, and E) as  Daniel Daranas pointed out, it is pushing the boundaries of what recursion can do.

Comment: I tested this side-by-side on an ivy bridge laptop (3.7Ghz, 8GB RAM & VS2008) and an AMD workstation (3.9Ghz, 16GB & VS2011BETA); they both crashed on the same string. And, it is the 65th item in the set - so it ran fine 64 times. I am going to dig further into this before removing the recursion, my intuition is that there is an issue setting up the string for this sequence of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you to the reviews and comments.

The functions are fine - this recursive function bundle requires that the string exists in the database it acts an, and the string checks prior to these incorrectly recognized a special condition and inserted a dummy char. There is the recursive function that precedes these two - I did not correctly see that I had written a bundle of three recursive functions - and that one was searching within parameters for a string longer than what exists in the database; apparently the parameters were wider than the stack. Checked into the parameters and one was not updated and was not controlling.

I fixed the special condition, the strings are now the same length and the search parameters are fixed.

the functions posted are not too complex.

Answer (score 3):

The call stack is a finite resource and can be exhausted like any other. The larger your function is (with respect to creation of local variables you create inside it) the larger the amount of space each call uses on the stack. It is something that is unavoidable with recursion unless you can restrict the number of recursive calls in some way.

Answer (score 3):

You can only go so deep with recursion before running out of stack space. Luckily, any recursive function can be re-written to be iterative. I believe the below is a correct iterative implementation of your vectorSearch, I'll leave the latter one to you.

```
string vectorSearch(string &check, int &direction, int n, int c, int r, int level) 
{
    while(true)
    {
        if ((direction == 1 && check.length() <= 1) || n == list.size()-1 ||(direction == 0 && check.length() > 1)) { //if reading and string is 1 char then pass over
            if (direction == 1){ //convert '???' into '?'
                string temp = "";
                bool wildToken = false;
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < check.length(); i++) {
                    temp+='?';
                    if (check.compare(temp) == 0) { check = '?'; wildToken = false; } //done,'???" case, return '?' token
                    else if (check[i] == '?') wildToken = true; //not done searching
                }
            }

            return check;
        } else if (list[n][c] == check || list[n][c] == ('0'+check)) {//add dummy '0'
                return list[n][r];
        }

        n++;
    }
}
```